# Decide probabilistically whether leaf labels in a decision tree sum to zero?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, graph-theory

I have the following problem, which might or might not be very easy to answer for someone with even a light background in statistics - but I don't even know where to start. Hence, I will give it a shot and post it here:

### Terminology

By a **decision tree** I will mean a directed, acyclic graph $G=(V,E)$ where each vertex $v\in V$ has indegree $0$ or $1$, and there is precisely one vertex with indegree zero, called the **root**.

For each vertex $v\in V$, let $\newcommand{\out}{\mathrm{out}}\delta_\out(v)=\{ e\in E \mid \exists w\in V: e=(v,w)\}$ be the set of outgoing edges.

For each edge $e=(v,w)\in E$, let $$p(e):=\frac{1}{\sharp\delta_\out(v)}$$ be the **probability** of this edge. For each leaf $v\in V_0:=\{ v\in V \mid \sharp\delta_\out(v)=0\}$, there is a unique path from the root to $v$. Let $e_1,\ldots,e_r\in E$ be the edges of this path. Then, we write $$p(v):=\prod_{i=1}^r p(e_i)$$ and call it the **probability** of this leaf.

### Problem Description

Let $a,b\in\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}\Z$ with $a<0<b$. Consider a decision tree $(V,E)$ whose leaves are labelled with integer values from the interval $[a,b]$. In other words, we have a function $\ell: V_0 \to \Z\cap[a,b]$.

> **Question:** Is the sum over all leaf labels equal to zero or not?
>
> i.e. decide whether $$\sum_{v\in V_0} \ell(v) = 0$$ or not.

Now in my case there are a *lot* of leaves, way too many to compute $\sum_{v\in V_0} \ell(v)$ explicitly. However, traversing a path from the root to some leaf $v$ and thereby computing $p(v)$ is easy.

Now, I was wondering: Is there a method to *probabilistically* answer the question from a smaller number of samples $v\in V_0$ together with the values $p(v)$ and $\ell(v)$?
Unfortunately, I do not know anything about the distribution of the values along the leaves.

Comment: Unless there’s some relationship between the $p(v)$ and the function $\ell$, it seems unlikely that the ability to calculate former easily will help much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by sampling leaves according to $p$ and averaging $\ell/p$. Its expected value is

$$
\sum_{v\in V_0}p(v)\frac{\ell(v)}{p(v)}=\sum_{v\in V_0}\ell(v)
$$

as desired. You can use the [Chebyshev inequality for finite samples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Finite_samples) to obtain an upper bound on the probability that the actual sample would have been obtained if the sum were zero, or you could assume an approximately normal distribution and do a standard $z$-test.

Comment: Perfect, this looks to be *exactly* what I am looking for. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @rattle: You're welcome!